# Error when using input() pyqgis (RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin) QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I need the user to input a value. I'm using `input()` on qgis python console, but getting this error:

> RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin

How can I solve it?

Comment: I don't think you can use input() in a pyqgis script unless you are executing from a CMD window - the python window isn't stdin or stdout. You would need to ask your question in a form of some sort.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35707849/1863709 This answer may help you, but it ist qt4, not qt5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QInputDialog
def getTextInput(title, message):
    answer = QInputDialog.getText(None, title, message)
    if answer[1]:
        print(answer[0])
        return answer[0]
    else:
        return None
```

To ask for a user input in QGIS-Console, you can use a QDialog object. There are some kinds of "ready to use" dialogs you could choose from. One of them is QInputDialog which itself can be shown with different types of widgets to get users choice. Above I used the Method getText() which opens a dialog with a single line input. Please read the [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html) to get more informations about that.

You also can call QInputDialog directly in the Python console:

```
answer = QInputDialog().getText(None, "Input", "Your input:")
```

`answer` is always a tuple like (text, ok) to examine, if input was cancelled and what input was made.